# URL shortening in django

Tags: python, django

I want to write a small django app that will shorten all the internal urls of the project. Till now i have got [short_url](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/short_url) which is pretty much what we want. Except it accepts only an int. Now there are a couple of other parameters also that we need to encode in the url. Need to know how can that be done.

Initially we though of **hash** based implementation, but we would need to store that in our databases so that is no good.

**Encrypting** data with key was also an option but the output is too long for short url.

Can someone suggest a library or algorithm that can be used for the same. unlike short_url, we have ascii data also. And as far as possible we would like the application to be stateless (no storage in DB) or if inevetable at-least not check DB every time if the url has been generated (low / no collision)

**EDIT**

For an example currently we have url format as /project/application .application is a list that is associated with the project. Now what we need is a bijective function that takes in project+application and gives out short url. (/Gjd73 for example). project name is defined by out users and application name is predefined in our database.

there can be any number of projects and application, both of them are ascii, but because there pk value can also be used in case its more useful than the ascii name.

Comment: You're going to have to store the state info somewhere. Assuming you want that info to persist across server restarts and/or multiple instances of the server, a DB is about your only option. Note: caching the info is possible, but can bring its own problems.

Comment: @PeterRowell have a look at the lib link that i added, that does not store in db, its kind of one-one function. Also at the same time, i did mention that i have no problem storing in DB, unless i don't need to make a query to validate that if the url exists every time i generate a new one. :)

Comment: Can you show some example URLs?

Comment: @AlexHall i am not putting in the url's directly, rather i am taking data off database. So there are two important parameters, one is project name and other is application name. So normally the urls are like /<project_name>/<application_name> what i need is a bijective function that takes in project name and application name and spits out a short url. :)

Comment: Tell us more about these parameters. How many different values does each one have? Does each project have its own set of applications? Might there be many more projects/applications in the future? Also it sounds like you already have rather short, readable URLs, why do you want to shorten them?

Comment: @AlexHall just added more to the question. yes there can be more projects as well as applications in the future. there is no saying how many values can they have. If it makes it simpler, consider using pk rather that there name.Initially we used to maintain a separate table with both of them and used the library with pk of the third table. Hope this answers what you wanted

Comment: So do you have a projects table and an application table with a foreign key to the application table and both tables have integer primary keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in your database, every "application" is `ForeignKey`-related to a parent "project", you can drop the "project" name/Id from you URL path.

A path like `exmple.com/12345` (where "12345" is your application `pk`) is about as short as it gets.

You can even make it shorter and [Base64 encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) that number, so you get an even shorter alphanum value.